# No actualiza datos API REST JAVA con Jersey

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, jersey

Tengo montada un **API** en [java](/questions/tagged/java) utilizando [jersey](/questions/tagged/jersey), cree una clase que tiene los metodos **REST** y esta funcionando, ingreso datos desde el cliente **POSTMAN** donde *GET*, *POST*, *PUT*, y *DELETE* funcionan, envió *POST* o *PUT* se ejecutan correctamente, pero después de haber enviado estos métodos el *GET* me retorna los datos sin actualizar.

Para poder ver los cambios con el GET debo bajar el servidor, no se donde revisar, adjunto Bean en donde se creo el servicio **REST**:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/docente")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class DocenteFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Docente> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ApiSilaboPU")`
private EntityManager em;`

public DocenteFacadeREST() {
    super(Docente.class);
}

@POST
@Override
public void create(Docente entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
public void edit(@PathParam("id") int id, Docente entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Docente find(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
public List<Docente> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}
}
```

Mi unidad de persistencia:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ApiSilaboPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>poliSilabo</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties/>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Clase Docente

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "docente")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Docente.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Docente d"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Docente.findById", query = "SELECT d FROM Docente d WHERE d.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Docente.findByCedula", query = "SELECT d FROM Docente d WHERE d.cedula = :cedula"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Docente.findByNombre", query = "SELECT d FROM Docente d WHERE d.nombre = :nombre"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Docente.findByCategoria", query = "SELECT d FROM Docente d WHERE d.categoria = :categoria")})
public class Docente implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "cedula")
private String cedula;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
@Size(max = 15)
@Column(name = "categoria")
private String categoria;

public Docente() {
}

public Docente(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCedula() {
    return cedula;
}

public void setCedula(String cedula) {
    this.cedula = cedula;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}

public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Docente)) {
        return false;
    }
    Docente other = (Docente) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "org.api.data.Docente[ id=" + id + " ]";
}    
}
```

Comment: Parece que todo está como debería. Lo único que se me ocurre es que no se estén manejando bien las sesiones y transacciones de/a base de datos. Por favor agrega la configuración de tu PersistenceUnit y de tu datasource o conexión a base de datos para investigar más al respecto.

Comment: ¿Puedes pasar el código correspondiente a la entidad ***Docente***?